# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.thrift.TFilterTransport

Tags: scala, hadoop, jdbc, hive, cloudera

I'm very new to hive and Hadoop,I'm trying to connect hive table from remote server and experiencing below error

```
object LoadData {

    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

        val HiveJDBCDriver = "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver"
        val filePath="/home/sparky/sample.txt"
        var connection: Connection = null
        Class.forName(HiveJDBCDriver)

  val con:Connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive2://xxxxx.xxxxx.com:10000/xevl_lcp;principal=hive/xxxxx.xxxxx.com@company.com;mapred.job.queue.name=lcp;
  AuthMech=1;SSL=1;user=xxxx;password=xxxx;SSLTrustStore=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_45/jre/lib/security/jssecacerts")


  }
  }
```

error

```
[main] INFO org.apache.hive.jdbc.Utils - Supplied authorities: xxxxx.xxxxx.com:10000
[main] INFO org.apache.hive.jdbc.Utils - Resolved authority: xxxxx.xxxxx.com:10000
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.thrift.TFilterTransport
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: You are missing one or more dependencies on the classpath.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel could you tell me which dependencies missing?

Comment: Check the documentation of that driver.

Comment: org.apache.hadoop.hive.thrift.TFilterTransport class comes from hive-shims jar.